# iPhone, what would be the size of a UITableView row icon / button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I've adding a logo to the right of a standard size row in a UITableView.

However, I've added an image which is 25 by 25 and it seems quite small.

I'm not viewing it on a retina device.

It looks like its being resized and looks awful.

But I just wondered what the standard size would be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default rowHeight in a UITableView is 45, so an image with a height of 40 would fit well.

If your 40x40 image is called cellImage.png, create an identical one of size 80x80 called cellImage@2x.png for decent display quality on retina devices.

Answer (score 0):

29 x 29 would be a good size for a standard table cell image.

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` (blue circle with white '>') is 29 x 31 (taller to account for its shadow).